# Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I got the Sony MDR-ZN770BN connected to my PC via bluetooth. But I can only use A2DP. When I switch it to HSP, I get message "Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit", so no skype calls possible.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Try changing to "off" profile before switching to headset

Comment: I confirm that changing profile to "off" and then back to "a2dp" works on Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: How is your comment related to the question? @wlk

Comment: As of Xubuntu 18.04 LTS (in April 2020) changing profile in Blueman to "off" and then to "Headset" does not work with gen 1 Apple Airpods.

Comment: Ubuntu is tracking the problem in https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1576559  Apparently, it's been fixed in release 21.10.

Answer (score 60):

I had the similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04 with Galaxy Earbuds+ and here is how I solved it:

My earbuds profiles were A2DP, AVRCP and HFP and no support for HSP. Pulseaudio only supports HSP out-of-the-box. That's why I couldn't switch to HSP/HFP. In order to make HSP/HFP work, you have to enable HFP on pulseaudio which needs ofono.

1. Install `ofono`:

   ```
   sudo apt install ofono
   ```
2. Config pulseaudio to use ofono:

- Goto `/etc/pulse/default.pa` find the line `load-module module-bluetooth-discover` and change it in `load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=ofono`.
- Add the user `pulse` to group `bluetooth` to grant the permission: `sudo usermod -aG bluetooth pulse` (probably it's already correct)
- VERY IMPORTANT: To grant the permission, add this to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/ofono.conf` (before `</busconfig>`):

  ```
    <policy user="pulse">
      <allow send_destination="org.ofono"/>
    </policy>
  ```

3. Provide `phonesim` to `ofono`. In order to make ofono work, you have to provide a modem to it! You can install a modem emulator called phonesim (implemented by ofono) to make it work:

- install `ofono-phonesim` (in some distros it is called `phonesim`). in Ubuntu 18.04 (for Ubuntu 20.04 follow [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242450/when-will-add-ofono-phomesim-to-the-focal-repository-20-04)):

  ```
   sudo apt install ofono-phonesim
  ```
- Configure phonesim by adding the following lines to `/etc/ofono/phonesim.conf`:

  ```
    [phonesim]
    Driver=phonesim
    Address=127.0.0.1
    Port=12345
  ```
- Restart `ofono`:

  ```
   sudo systemctl restart ofono.service
  ```
- Start `phonesim`:

  ```
   ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml
  ```

Note that the command can be `phonesim`. To make sure phonesim is started correctly you can clone the ofono repo and use their test scripts:

```
cd /tmp
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ofono/ofono.git
cd ofono/test
./list-modems
```

You should see the modem in the result. You might have to first enable the modem by executing `enable-modem` and `online-modem` scripts in the same directory.

- Once the modem is enabled, you should be able to enable HFP profile.

4. Autostart phonesim. Since you have executed phonesim manually, after every restart you should execute it again. Instead you can install `ofono-phonesim-autostart` which will start the phonesim as a service.

References:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697709/692422
- https://docs.plasma-mobile.org/Ofono.html

Comment: This solved it for me with AirPods on Ubuntu 18.04 Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful write up.  Thanks a lot!  I think you cna skip the *Goto /etc/pulse/default.pa find the line load-module module-bluetooth-discover and change it in load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=ofono.* step, since PA in default mode will use either profiles.

Comment: I've never been so clueless when following orders, but it actually got my Huawei Freelace headphones to work! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This helped me with Ubuntu 18.04 for Airpods Pro!

Comment: `ofono-phonesim-autostart` is not really working for me. How do I set it up?

Comment: When I try to run `./enable-modem`, I get the following error: `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.ofono.Error.Failed: Operation failed` What does it mean and how do I get around it?

Comment: My problem with `./enable-modem` was that I didn't have `phonesim` running while enabling the modem. The thing is that the previous command - `ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml` - has to be left running, then `enable-modem` works.

Comment: where is enable-modem located?

Comment: @timekeeper if you cloned the `ofono` git repository into `tmp` as described above, then it should be in the `/tmp/ofono/test` directory

Comment: @iSWORD I couldn't make my Huawei Freelace work with this method on Xubuntu 20.10. I also tried to restore my system back to 20.04 and tried again, but no luck. (Note: I didn't do "ofono-phonesim-autostart" step.) Can you help me on this? Share your steps maybe?

Comment: I had to use `./enable-modem /phonesim` and `./online-modem /phonesim` in order to earphones mic to work but output quality becomes terrible so I prefer using Internal Microfone Built-in and discard this solution.

Comment: How did you actually come up with all these steps? I mean, how did you even consider the "ofono" stuff to be needed?

Comment: feels like tutorial is incomplete by the end, the "ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml" , just hangs. Where to enable modem , which directory left to decide to the poor reader. Found 100 ofono polluted dirs. It is disgraceful to expect ubuntu to support airpods in 2021 out of the box. One day ... we say for last 30 years. Deleting all these voodoo packages and just accepting that i will have to switch to usb headphones to talk.

Comment: Running only `ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml` didn't work in my case, you also have to clone that git repo shared above and run `./enable-modem` every time. That's how I got my Sony WH-XB900N headphones working but now there's some small but constant noise on my headphones, not sure why that would be but that's annoying as well. Anyway, thank you for the answer! At least I got them working finally.

Comment: It worked for me the first time I did it. Then tried to automate its start with the other answer you posted under this one and it hasn't worked again since then.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. Everything seems to go as expected with creating the modem, starting it and checking it, but when I try to change the profile in blueman to `Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)` I get the error message `Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit`.

Comment: I have successfully implemented the solution by concatenating the two answers of this topic but to make it work, every time the PC is restarted, I have to restart pulseaudio with "pulseaudio -k". How do I resolve?

Comment: I could got it to work on Ubuntu 20.04 but it was very unstable, the source (Input) was changed after a couple of minutes in the middle of call. Worse than that, the `ofonod` suddenly gets somehow too busy and turns CPU up to 100% and i have to kill it… I'll undo everything and hope that a stable solution gets packed soon in the near future releases, not giving haters a chance to criticize the usability of Linux, anyhow TWS bluetooth devices are around since a couple of years!

Comment: Getting `Unable to locate package ofono-phonesim` when trying to install `phonesim`

Comment: @backslashN there's a link to another question with new ppa for the package https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242450/when-will-add-ofono-phomesim-to-the-focal-repository-20-04

Comment: After several hours trying everything until find your tutorial. I can confirm it works with JBL LIVE650BTNC Headphone. Now I can use it as input source also (microphone as HFP).

Comment: This tutorial does work, to be sure; but HFP will leave you with a very low quality sound input and even worse sound output. Not practical.

Answer (score 49):

I was facing the same issue with Oneplus Wireless Z Bass edition. My headset microphone was not detected by PulseAudio and the problem is that my headphones  don't have HSP profile, only HFP profile. After trying for 2 days, I came to the solution of replacing PulseAudio with Pipewire sound server, which supports HSP, HFP and A2DP by itself. So there will be no need to install any other utility like `ofono`, `phonesim`. Also, to be noted that my problem wasn't resolved even after following all the steps to configure `ofono` in PulseAudio. So I came up with the steps to replace PulseAudio with PipeWire.

Here is the detailed article I have written to resolve this problem, the steps of which I'm also adding here. You can follow it and most probably be able to solve your problem.

[Bluetooth headset microphone not detected](https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0)

Open your terminal and follow these steps:

1. We will use a PPA for adding Pipewire to Ubuntu 20.04, which is maintained regularly:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
   ```
2. To update the PPA packages in your system do:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire
   ```
4. There is also a dependency needed to be installed with Pipewire, otherwise you will face the issue of *“Bluetooth headset won’t connect after installing pipewire”*. Install the dependency by:

   ```
   sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
   ```
5. Now, to install the client libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
   ```
6. Reload the daemon:

   ```
   systemctl --user daemon-reload
   ```
7. Disable PulseAudio:

   ```
   systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
   ```
8. If you are on Ubuntu 20.04, you also need to “mask” the PulseAudio by:

   ```
   systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
   ```

   I am not sure but, if possible, you can try to run this on other versions too.
9. After a new update of Pipewire, you also need to enable `pipewire-media-session-service`:

   ```
   systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service
   ```
10. You can ensure that Pipewire is now running through:

    ```
    pactl info
    ```

    This command will give the following output, in Server Name you can see:

    ```
    PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.28)
    ```

    Things should be working by now and you can see your microphone.

---

If it doesn’t show up, then try restarting Pipewire by this command:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire
```

Also, you need to uninstall `ofono` and `ofono-phonesim` if you have them installed.

```
sudo apt remove ofono
sudo apt remove ofono-phonesim
```

If it’s still not showing your microphone, you can try rebooting once and remove and pair your Bluetooth device again to check if it works now.

I hope I have helped you solve your problem.

If you want to rollback all the changes we did, you can do it by using:

```
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire-media-session.service
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

---

Copied from comments, in case of the error "Connection failure: Connection refused":

do this step:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be the accepted answer!! Just one thing, on your Medium post the hyphen autocorrect/formatting broke the `systemctl` commands, e.g. it looks like `systemctl — user daemon-reload` instead of `systemctl --user daemon-reload`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! It really motivates me. Yes, even I saw this problem on Medium but couldn't fix the problem; that's why I posted steps separately.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Confirmed to work with Lenovo HT30. Using the previous approach with ofono did not lead me to any result

Comment: This also works with my JBL endurance headset, much simpler then the setup with ofono as well.

Comment: When running `pactl info` I get `Connection failure: Connection refused. pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused` even after I restarted it. Any clue what this could mean?

Comment: For connection fail: systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse is missing after systemctl --user restart pipewire

Comment: All works. but profiles HSP, HFP are absent

Comment: I'm having the same issue as Andrey.....

Comment: Just as the prevous 2 commenters, this seems to have worked on Ubuntu 21.10, but audio profiles are again without input (Philips SHB3595 headset). Instead of A2DP + non-working HFP, I see A2DP, A2DP + some codec, A2DP + some codec XQ (extra quality?). In sound preferences, I see input methods: onboard microphone, monitor for built-in analog stero, monitor for Philips headset (which means what it plays, not the mic).

Comment: Thanks man, haven't tried the solution yet, but i also have OnePlus Bullets Wireless Z bass edition and i had lost all hope for the mic to work finally seeing this is awesome.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it worked great for me, on the contrary with the first answer... how is it that Ubuntu does not support Bluetooth Hear Phones by default as plug and play in 2021???

Comment: It works fine with OnePlus buds pro and Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I thought it wasn't working at all, because my Audacity kept seeing only the onboard microphone. But the last command (restart pipewire-pulse) saved it! Several years I wanted but couldn't use bluetooth headsets! Finally it works!

Comment: This helped me to make work my airpods 3 clone's mic with ubuntu 20.04. Thanks

Comment: `pactl info` shows me `Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)`, but still I get error when connecting my device through bluetoothctl: `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable`.

Answer (score 16):

I originally posted this as an edit to @alisabzevari's post, but the edit was rejected :( I still think the information is very valuable, and I wouldn't like to lose it, so I'm posting it as an answer:

As of 2020-10-17, in Ubuntu 20.04 `ofono-phonesim-autostart` is not available. What you could do is create the following `systemd` units to start it as a daemon on startup:

To run `ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml` on startup as a systemd unit, create the file `/etc/systemd/system/ofono-phonesim.service` (as root) with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run ofono-phonesim in the background
    
[Service]   
ExecStart=ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]   
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After `ofono-phonesim` runs, you'll need to also enable and put the `phonesim` modem online. I (@Zoltán) did this by creating another `systemd` unit file that depends on the above `ofono-phonesim` `systemd` unit. Put the following contents in `/etc/systemd/system/phonesim-enable-modem.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable and online phonesim modem
Requires=ofono-phonesim.service
    
[Service]
ExecStart=/<path-to-cloned-ofono-git-repo>/test/enable-modem /phonesim
ExecStart=/<path-to-cloned-ofono-git-repo>/test/online-modem /phonesim
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run the following commands to run both daemons:

```bsh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable ofono-phonesim.service
sudo systemctl enable phonesim-enable-modem.service
sudo service phonesim-enable-modem start
```

Check if the service is running with

```bsh
sudo service phonesim-enable-modem status
```

Finally, restart `pulseaudio` with `pulseaudio -k`. Now you should be able to switch the profile to `headset_head_unit`.

Comment: Thanks for writing this. I also don't know why your edit got rejected. StackExchange has some strict rules.

Comment: Getting error when executing command `sudo service phonesim-enable-modem.service start` as `Failed to start phonesim-enable-modem.service.service: Unit phonesim-enable-modem.service.service not found.`

Comment: Before last command should be `sudo service phonesim-enable-modem.service start`

Comment: Thanks @AndriySlobodyanyk, that's correct and I see your edit was already approved.

Comment: @timekeeper see Andriy's comment, there was an error in my post.

Comment: I have successfully implemented the solution by concatenating the two answers of this topic but to make it work, every time the PC is restarted, I have to restart pulseaudio with "pulseaudio -k". How do I resolve?

Comment: Walked through it. ofono.service is running, ofono-phonesim too, phonesim-enable-modem started, but nothing changed. HFP audio profile still not working. :(

Answer (score 4):

I tried everything i possibly could, even the above answers. But i couldn't use the microphone of my headset. So i found another way to use a mic.

**All you need is an** **Android phone which has bluetooth**.

Firstly, go to google playstore on your phone and download a bluetooth microphone app.

I used this one (Simple Bluetooth Mic): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.google.chrischan.simplebluetoothmic

Alternatively, you can use this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wimlog.com.myandroidtest4.

Connect the phone's bluetooth to your PC.

Now connect your bluetooth headset to the PC.
(Both the devices must be connected simultaneously)

Open the Simple Bluetooth Mic App on your phone, click on speak.

Voila, that's it.

Basically you are using your phone's mic, because we can't use the bluetooth headset for both audio input and output.(changing from A2DP to HSP everytime you need to use the headset mic is irritating af)

If this doesn't work, go to your sound settings and choose the input device as your phone's bluetooth.

HOPE THIS HELPS :)

Comment: Many BT headsets cannot be connected to two devices at the same time.

Comment: @FranMarzoa It's not about connecting BT headset to two different devices but connecting phone and headset to the PC and using headset's headphones along with phone's microphone.

Comment: @Daniel Oh I see, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered this problem after some decent uptime (260 days or so), `pulseaudio -k` did not help, neither did switching audio profile to "off".

Restarting bluetooth (`systemctl restart bluetooth`) did.

Comment: restarting bluetooth service helped for me! thank you :-) I didn't attempt the solutions mentioned in the other answers. Just FYI

Comment: I'm glad I tried this first!  This instantly fixed the problem.  Thanks!