# Can't change profile to HSP for Bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I bought a Bluetooth headset cause I'm tired of wires. The headset supports A2DP, HSP, HFP and AVRCP.

I paired the headset correctly, and was greeted with the microphone not showing in the input tab of sound settings. This makes sense since the headset was in A2DP. I tried to change it to HSP/HFP in able use the microphone, but nothing seemed to happened.

Then I tried to do all of this via Blueman. Blueman complained `Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit`.

I've tried unpairing the device and pairing it again, setting the profile to off and then to HSP/HFP, but the same thing happens. It seems like I can only switch to A2DP, which only allows to hear, not use the mic.

In case it's necessary, the headset model is AV620 by Avenzo.

Comment: I have a similar issue: Whenever I switch the input to the headset, it changes to HSP/HSF (terrible quality)

Comment: @OndraŽižka Some research has lead me to learn that Bluetooth doesn't support high quality audio listening and capturing at the same time. My problem is I can't even switch to HSP/HFP to enable low quality playback and capture. I can only use A2DP. I thus am only able to have playback, no audio capture.

Comment: I think that answers my question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004712/audio-profile-changes-automatically-to-hsp-bad-quality-when-i-change-input-to
Are you sure about it? Even Bluetooth 4.0?

Comment: Switching to low quality 2-way works for me in 17.10. Perhaps try upgrading? But the resulting quality in my case is really low, I didn't hear such "low bitrate" sound since around 8 years back. What's the top supported parameters of HSP/HFP?

Comment: @OndraŽižka I am currently running 17.10, but gave up trying to set up Bluetooth headphones shortly after posting this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to change profile to headset\_head\_unit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit)

Answer (score 4):

Sad story,
Seems that your bluetooth card has not a fully compatible driver with bluez or whatever as mine :(.

I solved following [this guide](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-failed-to-change-profile-to-headset_head_unit/) and building two stupid scripts

#### Getting ready

Install ofono

```
sudo apt install ofono
```

Config pulseaudio to use ofono:

- Goto /etc/pulse/default.pa find the line load-module module-bluetooth-discover and change it in load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=ofono.
- Add the user pulse to group bluetooth to grant the permission: sudo usermod -aG bluetooth pulse (probably it's already correct)
- VERY IMPORTANT: To grant the permission, add this to /etc/dbus-1/system.d/ofono.conf (add this before </busconfig>):

  ```
  <policy user="pulse">
    <allow send_destination="org.ofono"/>
  </policy>
  ```

Provide phonesim to ofono.
In order to make ofono work, you have to provide a modem to it! You can install a modem emulator called phonesim (implemented by ofono) to make it work:

- install ofono-phonesim (in some distros it is called phonesim). in Ubuntu 18.04 (for Ubuntu 20.04 follow this link):

```
 sudo apt install ofono-phonesim
```

- Configure phonesim by adding the following lines to /etc/ofono/phonesim.conf:

```
[phonesim]
Driver=phonesim
Address=127.0.0.1
Port=12345
```

- Restart ofono:

```
sudo systemctl restart ofono.service
```

- Clone ofono repository (contains useful scripts)

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ofono/ofono.git destination/path
```

#### Then, *every time*  you want to enable hfp/hsp:

```
ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml &
```

then use

```
path/to/cloned/repo/test/enable-modem /phonesim
```

then restart pulseaudio with

```
pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start
```

Now you should see a microphone device.

#### When you want to go back to a2dp:

```
path/to/cloned/repo/test/disable-modem /phonesim
```

then restart pulseaudio with

```
pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start
```

eventually restart pulseeffects with

```
pulseeffects --quit && pulseeffects &
```

Lately i'm not using this because it's not always working, and so using a jack is faster.

Hope it helps :)

edit: Added getting ready section
edit 2: Added git clone step

Comment: What's the link for Ubuntu 20.04? `E: Unable to locate package ofono-phonesim`

Comment: check this out -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242450/when-will-add-ofono-phomesim-to-the-focal-repository-20-04

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so put this as an answer.

> Lately i'm not using this because it's not always working, and so using a jack is faster.

After removing `headset=ofono` from
`load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=ofono`
and restarting `pulseaudio` the speakers work again with microphone in Ubuntu 20.04.

> E: Unable to locate package ofono-phonesim

See answer here: [Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit).