# When will add ofono-phonesim to the focal repository (20.04)?

Tags: bluetooth

HFP bluetooth does not work, and phonesim is in the xenial and bionic repositories. Does anyone know when it will be added to focal?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The package was removed from Debian Unstable [at 2019-09-13](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ofono-phonesim), so it will not be until official port to Qt5.

You can install it from some [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esmoser/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth) for both 20.04 LTS and 20.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:smoser/bluetooth
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ofono-phonesim
```

Comment: Works! Thank you friend!

Comment: Doesn't work for `20.10` - any tips?

Comment: For 20.10 see update above.

Comment: 20.10 workaround no more needed, PPA now supports groovy

Comment: @VanniTotaro thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for 22.04 ?