# Bluetooth won't switch to headset for H800 in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, xubuntu, bluetooth, headset

My Logitech H800 connects successfully via Bluetooth dongle to Xubuntu 20.04 and sound can be played through the headphones. But I can't use the microphone because the audio profile is High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink). It is not permitted to change the profile to Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) as this gives the error "Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit".

A solution was offered for this problem in Ubuntu 18.04 at [Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit) however it seems inapplicable to Xubuntu 20.04.

Although I have a configuration file at /etc/ofono/phonesim.conf there is no executable for phonesim or ofono-phonesim. Nor does there seem to be anything of that nature in the repository, so it is not clear how, if at all, it could be installed.

Is there a solution to the problem that will work for Xubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I have a similar problem in Ubuntu 18.04 and the ofono solution did not work. To reproduce:
$ pactl set-card-profile 2 off  #ok
$ pactl set-card-profile 2 headset_head_unit  #fails
Failure: Input/Output error
$ pactl set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink   #ok