# bluetooth headphones (Powerbeats Pro) not able to switch to hsp/hfp Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am currently able to use my powerbeats pro as headphones with Ubuntu 20.04. However, I would like to use my headphones as a headset in certain situations.

However, the microphone on my headphones doesn't get recognized by the computer and instead uses the built-in microphone on the laptop.

I try switching audio profiles from A2DP to HFP/HSP using blueman but whenever I do it says "failed to change profile to headset_head_unit". Also when I use pulseaudio volume control and I try to switch the profile to HFP/HSP it says it is "unavailable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I just went with following with this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit) to enable hfp/hsp bluetooth profile on the headset. However for some reason I can't change the volume when on hfp/hsp profile but I guess that's a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug report on this you can subscribe to and add your voice to the chorus:

- [Bluetooth headset HSP/HFP mode not working in Bionic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1768625)

168 people are affected by or interested in this bug. Adding your input to the problem will help get it solved sooner rather than later.