# Bluetooth headset Mic is not detected

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, headset

I am not able to use my Bluetooth headset Mic as a mic input in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation. I can use it as an Output device with profiles - `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` and `Headset Head Unit(HSP/ HFP)` but in the Input section, only the `Internal microphone - Built-in audio` is showing.

In google meet in sound settings, it is appearing as `Monitor of Infinity Glide 501`, but the sound is not getting recorded.

Model:
JBL Infinity Glide 501

Note it works flawlessly with mobile devices.
What could be the reason? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in this answer below-

[Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit)

Please note-

Need to install `ofono` and `phonesim` in order to make bluetooth headset work.

For ubuntu 20.04 `phonesim` is not there in the repository, but it is available in this PPA

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:smoser/bluetooth`

`sudo apt install ofono-phonesim`

Comment: Any idea what to do for `20.10`? The above ppa doesn't have an install for it.

Comment: I found the following- https://pkgs.org/download/ofono-phonesim, https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/ofono-phonesim/1.21-1, https://github.com/jpakkane/ofono-phonesim. check if any of these works