# Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth sound playing issues

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Recently dual booted the laptop with Ubuntu(with windows 10), initially it was running fine. But now every time i connect my Bluetooth device, it shows connected but no audio plays through it. I have tried almost all the possible methods on the web,like reinstalling the pulseaudio stuff, using pavucontrol an all. It worked for a while but not perfectly. I had to remove and pair my earphones once per use because otherwise sound only from one earbud would play. But now even that doesnt happen. It doesnt play any sound from the bluetooth speakers. I have tried in pavucontrol to redirect it to them, but then no sound comes out. What do I do? New user here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, PulseAudio Bluetooth stack is not very reliable, hope PipeWire will resolve these issues.

For me I found [BlueMan](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman) quite usable, whenever this issue occurs I simply disconnect and reconnect my headset from Blueman.
Make sure your audio profile is selected as A2DP Sink.

Give it a try, hope this will resolve your issue.

Edit: Regarding headset mic issue I followed this - [Bluetooth headset Mic is not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273737/bluetooth-headset-mic-is-not-detected/1274294#1274294)

Comment: I tried it but it gives this error - Failed to change profile a2dp_sink. The sound quality is low and it plays for only one of the earbuds. Also about pipewire do i replace it for pulse audio or? Further i am only able to change it to the headset unit.

Comment: Also, my blueman seems to have those send ubuntu problem thing.

Comment: Did you tried removing and reconnecting? Which profile it is selecting by default? Pipewire is not yet ready to replace pulseaudio, you may try experimenting with it.

Comment: I did try removing and reconnecting. By default it is at off

Comment: welp searched up the internet for fixing the ad2p_sink thing. Did that and now using through blueman works. thanks a lot