# Newly installed Ubuntu 20.04: Bluetooth headset sound and mic not working

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, microphone, headset

Bluetooth headset connected but the sound is not working and the mic is not showing as connected in newly installed Ubuntu 20.04.
I have tried many solutions but unfortunately failed.

Can anyone  Please Help me? I have attached an Image to understand the issue:

[image]

Comment: Did it work with the same hardware before installing Ubuntu (with another operating system)?

Comment: Yes @PierreALBARÈDE , It was working with same hardware before installing Ubuntu. It was working on Window 10 on same hardware.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE I have attached a ScreenShot. Can you please look into it. In screenshot, I have explained the Issue on Sounds Settings.

Comment: I have seen it but it does not precisely answer my question.  You should check also Blutooth settings.  I have a Bluetooth headset right now working with Ubuntu 20.10 (for listening radio).  However the Testing Headset panel "click a speaker to test" does not work.

Comment: When I click a speaker to test on Testing Headset panel . I am not listening any sound on click right or left speaker option.

Comment: The Test Headset panel may be bugged or both of us do not understand it but I can listen to the radio on Firefox.

Comment: You may obtain more information from the command `% sudo dmesg|grep Bluetooth`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to change profile to headset\_head\_unit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detailed article I have written to resolve this problem, the steps of which I'm also adding here. You can follow it and most probably be able to solve your problem.

Bluetooth headset microphone not detected

Open your terminal and follow these steps:

We will use a PPA for adding Pipewire to Ubuntu 20.04, which is maintained regularly:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
```

To update the PPA packages in your system do:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install the package:

```
sudo apt install pipewire
```

There is also a dependency needed to be installed with Pipewire, otherwise you will face the issue of “Bluetooth headset won’t connect after installing pipewire”. Install the dependency by:

```
sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
```

Now, to install the client libraries:

```
sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
```

Reload the daemon:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

Disable PulseAudio:

```
systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

If you are on Ubuntu 20.04, you also need to “mask” the PulseAudio by:

```
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
```

I am not sure but, if possible, you can try to run this on other versions too.
9. After a new update of Pipewire, you also need to enable pipewire-media-session-service:

systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service

You can ensure that Pipewire is now running through:

```
pactl info
```

This command will give the following output, in Server Name you can see:

```
PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.28)
```

Things should be working by now and you can see your microphone.

If it doesn’t show up, then try restarting Pipewire by this command:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire
```

If it’s still not showing your microphone, you can try rebooting once and remove and pair your Bluetooth device again to check if it works now.

I hope I have helped you solve your problem.

If you want to rollback all the changes we did, you can do it by using:

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

Refer original thread [Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit/1340778#1340778)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please format the commands to be typed as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit answer window.

Comment: Since you have copied this answer from another question, I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of the other question where you have copied your answer from.