# Bluetooth earphone sound stops after some time on A2DP setting

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a JBL earphone, I connect it to my Ubuntu 18.04. When I set configuration in A2DP the sound quality is good but it stops after some time and I have to restart pc and reconnect again in order to connect again. If I try to connect without restarting, laptop just hangs.
Surprisingly in the HCP config, it doesn't happen but sound quality is really bad and noisy.
I have tried reinstalling Bluez and Pulseaudio. I also tries connecting it through blueman.
Nothing works. Please help. Thanks in advance.
My laptop is Asus Vivobook Gaming Core.

Comment: I solved the issue using this thread. https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit/1340778#1340778

Comment: @Kandhaswamy thread addresses different problem