# No sound (or cracking sound) in Bluetooth wireless earphones automatic connection, and no Input Device detected for earphones

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome, a2dp

I am facing several issues with using Bluetooth earphones in `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`, having the kernel `5.4.0-80-generic`. The earphones work well in other operating systems.

`Issue 1`: Whenever I switch on the earphones, they automatically connect to my laptop's Bluetooth, but they are detected as keyboards, instead of earphones. So, I cannot hear sound from them, and within a couple of seconds, they get automatically disconnected. Logs from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 kernel: [230658.746268] input: Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input115
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event22)
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event22 13:86 fd 63 paused 0
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): always reports core events
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event22"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): device removed
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input115/event22"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 22)
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event22)
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (**) Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 kernel: [230658.857301] input: Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input116
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event22 13:86 fd 31 paused 1
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:86
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event23)
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (**) Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event23 13:87 fd 31 paused 1
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:87
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event23)
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event23 13:87 fd 78 paused 0
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): always reports core events
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event23"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event23 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event23 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event23 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): device removed
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input116/event23"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 23)
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event23 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event23 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug  3 17:11:58 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Aug  3 17:11:59 ashish-Inspiron-7570 bluetoothd[1365]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:a2dp_select_capabilities() Unable to select SEP
Aug  3 17:12:00 ashish-Inspiron-7570 acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 25
Aug  3 17:12:00 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) config/udev: removing device Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP)
Aug  3 17:12:00 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "fd" "63"
Aug  3 17:12:00 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note-L (AVRCP): device removed
Aug  3 17:12:00 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug  3 17:12:00 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:86
Aug  3 17:12:03 ashish-Inspiron-7570 acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 26
Aug  3 17:12:03 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) config/udev: removing device Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP)
Aug  3 17:12:03 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "fd" "78"
Aug  3 17:12:03 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event23 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): device removed
Aug  3 17:12:03 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug  3 17:12:03 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:87
```

When I connect to the earphones' Bluetooth manually from the GUI, they get connected and I can hear sound from them. Logs when manually connecting to the earphones are mentioned below.

`Issue 2`: The sound that I hear is not clear and it cracks in between. When I click on the "Sound" option in the settings, the sound becomes clear, similar to what I expect.

[Image: Bluetooth connection GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg5nb.png)

```
Aug  3 17:13:07 ashish-Inspiron-7570 bluetoothd[1365]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-source profile connect failed for 8C:85:80:2C:F2:35: Device or resource busy
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 kernel: [230728.120859] input: Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input117
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event22)
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event22)
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (**) Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event22 13:86 fd 63 paused 0
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): always reports core events
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event22"
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): device removed
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input117/event22"
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 22)
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event22 13:86 fd 31 paused 1
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2172]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:86
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7877]: (II) event22 - Soundcore Life Note (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug  3 17:13:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 gnome-shell[8535]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Aug  3 17:13:10 ashish-Inspiron-7570 bluetoothd[1365]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_8C_85_80_2C_F2_35/sep2/fd25: fd(38) ready
Aug  3 17:13:10 ashish-Inspiron-7570 rtkit-daemon[2321]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Aug  3 17:13:10 ashish-Inspiron-7570 rtkit-daemon[2321]: Successfully made thread 686940 of process 7796 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug  3 17:13:10 ashish-Inspiron-7570 rtkit-daemon[2321]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
```

`Issue 3`: The earphones have both sink and source in them, which works with other devices. But, on connecting them to Ubuntu, only the output works. I can't use the microphone present in my earphones.

In the GUI, the Input option is not listed for the earphones. It is only listed in the output device:

[Image: Sound Input and Output option GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r93Bc.png)

I think that is probably because of the A2DP configuration. Even from the above logs, we can see `a2dp-source profile connect failed`. From the GUI itself, I try to change A2DP to HSP/HFP, but find that it can't switch the profile:

```
Aug  3 17:14:08 ashish-Inspiron-7570 pulseaudio[7796]: Refused to switch profile to headset_head_unit: Not connected
```

So, I needed help with the above issues:

- Bluetooth earphones can automatically connect to Ubuntu.
- The sound that is played by earphones does not crack in between.
- I can simultaneously utilize the input and output of the earphones, instead of only the output.

What steps can I take to fix or debug these issues?

**Edit 1**:

Output of `lspci | grep Audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

Comment: This could be problem with PulseAudio, are you currently logged in as root?.

Comment: Yes, logged in as root

Comment: Update your question with output from `lspci | grep Audio`

Comment: Updated the question @Ruby

Comment: Audio driver is detected you may need to run the command `alsactl restore`

Comment: It did not fix the issue:

`alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
alsa-lib main.c:1021:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:0 (empty configuration)
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC3254" "HDA:10ec0295,102807ea,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x1028" "0x07ea"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method`

Running with sudo returns no output.

Comment: I hope this solves your problem. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

Comment: Nope, this did not solve. The last part was solved using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit) and [this](https://zambrovski.medium.com/using-bluetooth-headset-on-ubuntu-790ce6eecc2). For the first two parts, I just do it manually.