# Ofono install and config Ubuntu 20

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm following a guide on how to get ofono installed and configured on Ubuntu 20, and hit a block. I'm not well enough versed in linux to understand what I'm supposed to do at this point. Would anyone have any idea? Below is what the step is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"Now you will need to define and enable few services to start the ofono-phonesim as service.
To run ofono-phonesim -p 12345 /usr/share/phonesim/default.xml on startup as a systemd unit, create the file /etc/systemd/system/ofono-phonesim.service(as root) with the following contents:"

Comment: Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1301127/178692) what you are following?

Comment: Yes that's the one.

Comment: I was actually able to get past this step. However I've ran into a different issue. When I run the final commands, I get a error failed because the control process exited with error code. Looking into it it's (Code=exited, status=1/Failure) and I'm not sure why.